# как заменить массивы в игре через pymem

Tags: python, массивы, byte, bytearray, pymem

[image: Cheat Engine array]

```
import pymem

pm = pymem.Pymem("javaw.exe")
pm.write_???(0xC3F5683F,0x0000803F)
```

Нужно заменить `0xC3F5683F` на `0x0000803F`.

В `Cheat Engine` написано что это `array of byte`, но в `pymem` нет `write_arrayofbyte()` или что-то похожего.

Как заменить массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там есть [write_bytes(address, value, length)](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.Pymem.write_bytes) и [pattern_scan_module(handle, module, pattern, *, return_multiple=False)](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.pattern.pattern_scan_module), то есть придётся это делать в два этапа:

- найти искомую сигнатуру через `pattern_scan_module`
- пропатчить данные по найденным адресам через `write_bytes`

Примеры в документации вполне понятные с виду.

Comment: Как узнать количество байтов для записи:
import pymem
pm = pymem.Pymem("javaw.exe")

fmm = b".\xC3\xF5\x68\x3F"

module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "javaw.exe")
address = pymem.pattern.pattern_scan_module(pm.process_handle, module, fmm)


write_bytes(address, 0x0000803F, length)

Я понял так. Что поставить на место length?